# highlight text containing special characters in notepad++ program

Tags: notepad++, selection, highlight

I am trying to hightlight the text `2:` in NotePad++. So while I am on `2` this works fine...

[image: Image 1]

When I select `2:`, the whole thing goes away.

[image]

Any workaround to this? Looking to select the entire intended text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select "2:" -> Right click on selection -> Style token -> Using 1st Style.

You have five styles you can apply on different text pieces.

Answer (score 0):

To highlight a block of code in Notepad++, please do the following steps

1. Select the required text.
2. Right click to display the context menu
3. Choose Style token and select any of the five choices available ( styles from Using 1st style to using 5th style). Each is of different colors.

If you want to create your own style you can use Style Configurator under Settings menu.